# Configuring kubectl against remote clusters

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I followed the [Kubernetes docs for setting up a single node cluster as a Docker container](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html). I now have Kubernetes running on a remote Linux VM (say, `mykube01.example.com`).

I then downloaded and installed `kubectl` locally on my Mac laptop. I can run `kubectl version` and it verifies I have installed the correct version.

I then went to configure `kubectl` by [following this doc](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubeconfig-file.html) and created the following `~/.kube/config` file:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 clusters:
 - cluster:
      api-version: v1
      server: http://mykube01.example.com:8080
      name: testkube
```

When I run `kubectl cluster-info` I get:

```
Kubernetes master is running at http://mykuber01.example.com:8080
```

But when I run `kubetctl get nodes` I get:

```
The connection to the server mykube01.example.com:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry? I want to get to the point where I can keep going with that first Kubernetes doc and deploy nginx to the 1-node cluster via:

```
kubectl -s http://mykube01.example.com:8080 run-container nginx --image=nginx --port=80
```

But I can't do that until I get `kubectl` configured properly and correctly connecting to my remote "cluster".

Comment: Is the apiserver running on your Linux machine listening on all network interfaces? If the connection from your Mac is refused, that sounds like it may not be listening on an interface that is accessible remotely.

Comment: Just to make sure that the api server is running properly, may be you can try curl http://mykube01.example.com:8080/api/v1/nodes/ (or from a browser) from your laptop

Answer (score 2):

When you created the connection to your master, a file should be created:

```
/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
```

By default, your personal config is empty or missing. So, I copied the above mentioned kubelet.conf file as my `~/.kube/config` file. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

(moving the "reply" down into the "answer" so that this appears as "answered"

kubectl just uses HTTP(S) by default.  As the person said above, try using 'curl mykube01.example.com:8080/api/v1/nodes' or open that URL in a browser and see if that works.

If that works, but kubectl doesn't then there is a problem in kubectl or your config.  If curl or the browser don't work, the problem is in the network somewhere.